# How to do a smoke Test and Acceptance test in a Javascript Aplication?

Tags: javascript, tdd, bdd, acceptance-testing, smoke-testing

I want to do a smoke test in order to test the connection between my web app and the server itself.  Does Someone know how to do it? In addition I want to do an acceptance tests to test my whole application. Which tool do you recommend?

My technology stack is: backbone and require.js and jquery mobile and jasmine for BDD test.

Regards

Comment: Are you doing this test manually (by hand, e.g. open the page in a browser) or automated (writing code to test this functionality)?

Comment: I want to do a Job in Jenkins that run a test which performs the acceptance and smoke test. Currently I am investigating capybara, Have you used this tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a blog post where the author explain how to use capybara, cucumber and selenium outside a rails application and therefore can be use to test a javascript app. Here are the link: http://testerstories.com/?p=48

Answer (score 1):

When doing BDD you should always mock the collaborators. The tests should run quickly and not depend on any external resources such as servers, APIs, databases etc.

The way you would want to make in f.e. Jasmine is to declare a spy that pretends to be the server. You then move on to defining what would be the response of the spy in a particular scenario or example.

This is the best aproach if you want your application to be environment undependent. Which is very needed when running Jenkins jobs - building a whole infrastructure around the job would be hard to reproduce.

Make spy/mock objects that represent the server and in your specs define how the external sources behave - this way you can focus on what behavior your application delivers under specified circumstances.

Comment: Many thanks for you answer karolsojko. Nevertheless I don want to make unit tests, I want to do an acceptance tests that works with jenkins. I thought that the best option is capybara, Did you use this tool? Which tool do you recommend for acceptance test?

Comment: For acceptance tests (or actualy doing StoryBDD) a good choice would be Cucumber.js (https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js) or Kyuri (https://github.com/nodejitsu/kyuri) pick your poison ;)

Comment: Thank you karolsojko, one hour ago I could set up a ruby + capybara + cucumber app in order to run in jenkins and be part of my deployment pipeline :)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, but one tool we've been using for our very similar stack is [mockJSON](http://experiments.mennovanslooten.nl/2010/mockjson/).  It's a jQuery plugin that does a nice job both:

1. intercepting calls to a URL and instead sending back mock data and
2. making it easy to generate random mock data based on templates.

The best part is that it's entirely client side, so you don't need to set up anything external to get decent tests. It won't test the actual network connection to your server, but it can do a very good job validating that type of data your server would be kicking back. FWIW, we use Mocha as our test framework and haven't had any trouble getting this to integrate with our BDD work.

The [original mockJSON repo](https://github.com/mennovanslooten/mockJSON) is still pretty good, though it hasn't been updated in a little while.  My colleagues and I have been trying to keep it going with patches and features in [my own fork](https://github.com/mikeedwards/mockJSON).